# Debugging Gradle build files in Intellij / Android Studio

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle, android-studio

I am sometimes running into obscure problems with Gradle. Sometimes it helps if i am reading the source files or adding println statements to figure out what i can do and what the state is.

But i would really like to just place a breakpoint and list the internal state of variables. is that possible using Android Studio or IntelliJ ?

I would also love to ctrl-click to the DSL keywords so i can get some context.

Just placing a breakpoint and clicking "debug" from the list of gradle tasks does not work, it just runs the tasks without stopping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Original source](http://galenlin.github.io/en/android/2016/01/29/debug-gradle-on-android-studio.html)

## 1. Create a debugger

- Run -> Edit Configurations

[image]

- Add New Configuration

[image]

- Add Remote configuration

[image]

## 2. Open debug mode

```
$ export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

## 3. Start debugger

```
$ ./gradlew someTask -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false #!important, disable daemon mode
```

## 4. Attach debugger

- Set breakpoints

[image]

- Start debug

[image]

## 5. Disable debug mode

```
$ unset GRADLE_OPTS
```

Comment: i have not verified that yet, but it sounds very plausible. going to mark that one as the answer after verification!

Comment: duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587096/how-do-you-debug-java-annotation-processors-using-intellij

Answer (score 11):

You can't debug Gradle files. We may someday implement this, as it would obviously be a great thing, but it's a long ways off. We're in the process of adding more intelligence about syntax highlighting and analysis of build files. Well, actually, JetBrains is adding it to IntelliJ and we're picking it up. This will get better over the coming weeks and months.

Comment: Anyone know if there's any progress on this?