# How to debug a Gradle build.gradle file (in a debugger, with breakpoints)?

Tags: debugging, gradle

Is there a tool that will allow me to set breakpoints in a build.gradle file and step through tasks in a debugger?

Note:  I believe that I'm asking a different question than similar stackoverflow questions about debugging Gradle plugins, where (presumably) the intent is to step through custom Groovy or Java plugin code located in a separate file.  I want to set a breakpoint in a Gradle task in a simple build.gradle file, like...

```
task example {
   println "I want to set a breakpoint here"
}
```

...so that when I run `gradle example` I can inspect the context in a debugger.

(For those who would point me to IntelliJ...although JetBrains' website advertises that they support debugging Gradle scripts in IDEA UI, AFAICT this is untrue, as this was reported broken in IDEA13 EAP and hasn't been fixed in IDEA14. See [Debugging Gradle build files in Intellij / Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017433/debugging-gradle-build-files-in-intellij-android-studio) )

Is there any debugging tool that allows me to set a breakpoint in a build.gradle file, or is there something about the Gradle DSL that makes it fundamentally impossible to set breakpoints in a task such as my example, above?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

IntelliJ 2018.2 added the ability to debug Gradle scripts in a similar fashion to how you might run/debug other projects. You can see the announcement in the release notes [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-2-gradle).

Here is a screenshot of some of the documentation from 2018.2:

[image: IntelliJ documentation for debugging a Gradle script task]

It does not yet support the `kotlin-dsl` (see [gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/39](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/39)).

Answer (score 60):

There is the easier way:

just add in your command line `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon`

For example:
    `gradle nameOfTask -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon`

Then you should start your IDE and run remote debugging with localhost port 5005, that all.

Gradle is waiting to you, because standard option server=y

**org.gradle.debug**

When set to true, Gradle will run the build with remote debugging enabled, listening on port 5005. Note that this is the equivalent of adding `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005` to the JVM command line and will suspend the virtual machine until a debugger is attached.

[Link to docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

Comment: The documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html and the code at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/process/internal/JvmOptions.java#L143 suggests that yes, this is essentially equivalent to the answer provided by @baptiste-mesta .

Comment: My gradle build doesnt stop and wait for debugger to become attached?

Comment: gradle should stop and wait for debugger, could you show me the cmd?

Comment: `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true` works the first time I run gradle (v3.5), but not the second. This seems to be a problem with the gradle daemon.  So try running `gradle build -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon`, this works every time for me.

Comment: @neu242 I always get the output `To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked`. Don't you? I tried gradle 4.0 and 4.5.1.

Comment: The answer was written when there was gradle 3.4. I am not happy, that gradle is incompatible

Comment: I think you meant "Gradle is waiting to you, because standard option is suspend=y"

Answer (score 17):

Personnaly I do this when I need to debug build scripts:

Inside you terminal do

```
export GRADLE_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Then run your build

```
gradle clean install
```

Finally put some breakpoints and launch the remote debug configuration inside your IDE on the port 5005 and you’re good to go!

Comment: android studio keeps telling me the following error when i try this: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused"

Comment: when you run gradle clean install does the build stops on
"Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005"

Comment: The OP asked "Is there any debugging tool that allows me to set a breakpoint in a build.gradle file", so can you expand on "put some breakpoints"?

Comment: You are right, it's not working for breakpoints directly in build.gradle files.
I was thinking that because I had in my sources the plugins that i wanted to debug.
However you can put breakponts in the org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject on the configuration phase you want.
e.g. put you breakpoint on org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject#dependencies(Closure configClosure) to stop the jvm before your closure depedencies { ...} is called

Comment: AndroidStudio/Idea gets attached to port, but it doesn't stop on breakpoints. And bp are displayed withing an X mark. I guess jetbrains just can't determine which source is linked to which file

Comment: What does `launch the remote debug configuration inside your IDE` mean? How do you do that?

Comment: see here for intellij idea: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html

Comment: How can i remove that options later?

Comment: The export command will only affect the current shell session. Just open a new shell to "remove" that option

Comment: @11m0 [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html#541187ca) explains how to launch a `remote debug` session. TL;DR: choose Run > Edit Configurations... > Click the plus icon > select 'Remote JVM Debug' > accept the defaults and click 'Ok'

Answer (score 14):

`export GRADLE_OPTS`   does not work for me.

Try this:

**1 Add remote debug config**

[image]

-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

**2 Add breakpoint in Gradle**

[image]

**3**   `./gradlew your task --stacktrace -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false   -Dorg.gradle.debug=true`

**4 Attach debug in Android Studio**
click icon [image]

[image]

Then the breakpoint stops !!

[image]

If console is not going, click this in debug pannel in Android Studio.
[image]

Comment: doesn't works for me... it does nothing for an infinite time.

Answer (score 3):

After reading various answers here the following steps will help you debug `build.gradle` to being able to break and investigate variables inside any custom task. I am using Eclipse remote debugging facilities

1. Place this simple code where you want to break: `try {throw new RuntimeException('Break');} catch (RuntimeException e) {}`
2. As recommended start your task with `gradle mytask -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon` in the command prompt (don't have to do it in Eclipse)
3. In Eclipse do `Run -> Add Java Exception Breakpoint`, choose `RuntimeException` and click "OK"
4. Again in Eclipse go to `Run -> Debug Configurations -> Remote Java Application` and create new configuration that listens on `localhost:5005`. Name it whatever you want. Select a project that contains `build.gradle` you are debugging. Click `Apply` and `Debug`
5. At this point the execution will start but will pause at the Exception-throwing line. And you can then start looking at your variables in the `Debug -> Variables" view, inspect the stacktrace, step through the code etc.
6. No magic, alas, you will not see anything highlighted in `build.gradle` but you can pretty much guess where you are at
7. Obviously on subsequent runs you don't need step 3 and in 4 you can reuse previously created configuration
8. If you want to use this in the multiple places simply create a method, use different type of exception and feel free to enhance this idea in any way possible

For example:

```
void halt() {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException('Break');
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        print('Paused')
    }
}

task iterateDeclaredDependencies {
    doLast {        
        Object configs = configurations.all
        halt();
        print(configs)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Though I prefer to use one-liner from point 1 rather than extracted method

Answer (score 2):

1. run your command via Android Studio button

[image]

[image]

2. wait it's completion or cancel it's execution
3. ensure that your command shows here

[image]

4. run debug with this button

[image]

Comment: (1) This will debug the app/tests which are run via this build, not the build itself, (2) the button you pointed to is only for debugging an already-running app, I believe you meant the one further to the left

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8989"
```

then 2 gradle processes are listening :

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8989
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8989
```

I can connect to both of them with 2 remote debug launch configurations in Eclipse although it's the same port.