# gradle remote debugging process

Tags: java, gradle, build, remote-debugging

I am adding the `GRADLE_OPTS` to system environment variables as:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

I have created the remote debugger from InteliJ IDEA for this socket. I can debug the `build.gradle` file, but I can't enter into the scripts for example can't see the variable values .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug a Gradle build.gradle file (in a debugger, with breakpoints)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437636/how-to-debug-a-gradle-build-gradle-file-in-a-debugger-with-breakpoints)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are the steps to remotely debug gradle:

**Step-by-step guide**
1. Run your Gradle command
2. On the command line, execute your task normally, but add the following additional parameters:

```
-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs='-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=y'
```

The "`suspend=y`" part will pause the execution for you to attach a debugger.

**Attach a debugger:**

1. Open the Gradle source code in IntelliJ
2. Go to Run -> Edit Configurations
3. Add a new Configuration by clicking the + in the upper left corner
4. Select Remote, rename it if you choose, and click OK
5. Set your breakpoints
6. Go to Run -> Debug "" (defaults to "Unnamed")

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this as an alternate answer. For me this works as well
`./gradlew <command> --debug-jvm`

This does the same thing as above but with fewer arguments.