# How can i debugging gradle file(except build.gradle) in IntelliJ?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, jvm

I want to debug my gradle task in test.gradle which is not in build.gradle in IntelliJ IDEA.

Like this,
[test.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1J4t.png)
[debugTestwithGradle task in test.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L1MC.png)

So, I tried remote debugging follow these guides.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html?_ga=2.146766132.1892324613.1590646291-1406325537.1590646291#top
- [gradle remote debugging process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702073/gradle-remote-debugging-process)

But these guide does not work for me.

Is there any solution to debug gradle script?

Answer (score 1):

To debug gradle scripts, you just need to set the following VM option:

```
-Dorg.gradle.debug=true
```

And then attach debugger to standard port 5005.

See details here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting.html#sec:troubleshooting_build_logic

there is even an example how to do it in IntelliJ Idea:)

Comment: Thanks your answer! But I still have a problem with debugging. I follow that guide, then it's working with task in build.gradle, but still cannot debug task in test.gradle (which file i made it). Is there any different option in build.gradle script?

Comment: it should work for both files. How are you including test.gradle to your build? are you sure that task from test.gradle is executed?

Comment: I called debugTestwithGradle task(test.gradle) in debugTest task(build.gradle), then excute ./gradlew debugTest -Dorg.gradle.daemon.debug=true and attach remote debugger. So, It's working at debugTest task and can't debug debugTestwithGradle task.