# Debug gradle internal classes in IntelliJ

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I have a custom task, like this one:

`task hello {
    doLast {
        println 'Hello, World!'
    }
}`

Now I can set breakpoint on `doLast` and IntelliJ will stop there, but I'am unable to debug into gradle core classes, like for example: `org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject#task(...)`

Is is possible to attach Gradle sources for debugging Gradle internal classes in IntelliJ?

Comment: maybe this helps :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884925/6899896 ? also, you should configure the gradle wrapper to use a '*-all' distribution (e.g. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip` )

Comment: You migth also have to add dependency "gradleApi()   ( `dependencies {     compileOnly gradleApi()    }` ) to make Gradle source code available for debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to convert comment into answer, but essentially, @m-ricciuti is correct, what has to be done is:

- add `implementation(gradleApi())` (it's in Kotlin DSL) to `dependencies`
- specify `-all` distribution in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-all.zip
```

- create "Remote JVM Debug" run configuration in IntelliJ (all settings can be left "as is")
- run gradle with arguments `gradlew <task> -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon`, it will say "Starting daemon" and pause
- start the created run configuration via Debug button

This way, you can set breakpoints on `@TaskAction` methods, and a lot more, however, I still was not capable to set a breakpoint in a `CloseableHttpClient` or an `InternalHttpClient` classes. Which is essentially what I was most interested in, so if anyone knows more... please chime in!