# Debugging gradle files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea

I have read [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884925/7674438) that in IntelliJ IDEA is possible to debug gradle files.

Can I do the same thing on Android Studio? And how?

EDIT: my question is not duplicate because it regards not IntelliJ but only Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried to do it the same way as in IDEA?

Comment: I've setted breakpoints and start tasks in debug mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug a Gradle build.gradle file (in a debugger, with breakpoints)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437636/how-to-debug-a-gradle-build-gradle-file-in-a-debugger-with-breakpoints)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to debug Gradle, we have to create a new remote configuration in Android Studio.

**1.** Open "**EditRun/Debug configurations**" dialog:

[image: Edit configuration dialog]

Don't forget to add your breakpoint in the `build.gradle` file.

[image: Add gradle break point]

**2.** Once in "**Run/Debug Configuration**" click on the `+` icon to add a new configuration and then select `Remote`:

[image: Add remote configuration]

- You will be presented with the "**Remote**" configuration options.
- (**Optional**) rename configuration from "Unnamed" to whatever name you desire.
- Then click "**OK**"

[image: Rename remote configuration]

As you can see on the above image I've chosen "**Gradle Remote Debug**".

**3.** Now select your "**Remote**" configuration in the "**EditRun/Debug configurations**" dialog and go to "**Terminal**" in Android Studio and type the following command:

`./gradlew help -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon`

The above command option can be anything "help, tasks, etc." the only important attribute is `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon` and having the "Remote" configuration setup.

After inputting the above command hit "**Enter**" and you'll see that the command will start the Daemon and will be listening for the remote debugger as illustrated on the following picture.

[image: Start Daemon]

**4.** Now all that is left to do is to attach the debugger by clicking on the "**Debug**" icon in Android Studio.

[image: Debug icon]

Then if you haven't forgotten to set your breakpoint you'll see that Gradle will be executed and will stop at the breakpoint.

[image: Run to breakpoint]

**References:**
[Debugguing Build Logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/troubleshooting.html#sec:troubleshooting_build_logic)

Comment: This was way more helpful than the other similar answers I saw. It should be accepted.

Comment: Wow this was the blog help level solution! Thanks and it worked flawlessly on first attempt.

Comment: In windows I have to use command `.\gradlew "-Dorg.gradle.daemon.debug=true" help --no-daemon`. Without quotes it shoes error "Task '.gradle.daemon.debug=true' not found in root project"