# Find exact xml file causing issue during resource shrinking

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-resources

I am having **`shrinkResources true`** enabled in my Android project. When I am running the app is release mode, its throwing the below error.

> ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
> Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.

I am able to suppress the issue temporarily by adding `enableNewResourceShrinker=false` in **gradle.properties**.

But I need to find exact file , which is causing the issue.

I couldn't able to find any typo or additional characters or additional line after the xml header, in any xml files.

Is there any way to find out which file is causing this resource shrinking build issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was a tough one to crack. But here's what I did:

- Ran the `shrinkResources` task with --trace to get the breaking line. Using Android Studio, opened the `ToolsAttributeUsageRecorder` file

[image: A screenshot of Android Studio's console showing the stack trace for the Gradle task error]

- Followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408741/debugging-gradle-files-in-android-studio) to set a Gradle Debugger. Started the gradle task in debug mode: `gradlew :app:shrinkDevDebugRes -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon`
- Set a breakpoint in this line to get the path of the offending file
  [image: A screenshot of the source code for ToolsAttributeUsageRecorder.processRawXML]
- Since I have thousands of resources, I set the breakpoint to not suspend, log the path instead
  [image: A screenshot of the breakpoint editor in Android Studio showing the "suspend" checkbox unchecked, the "Evaluate and log" field checked]

The last line in the debug console was the offending resource. In my case a Vector Drawable without header