# Breakpoints not hit in IntelliJ when debugging my Java annotation processor

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I've written a Java annotation processor following [Hannes Dorfmann's](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101) tutorial. My project uses Maven. When I try to debug it using `mvnDebug` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587096/how-do-you-debug-java-annotation-processors-using-intellij?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) article, everything works except that my breakpoints are not hit in IntelliJ.

1. I can run `mvnDebug clean compile` from the command line.
2. I can attach IntelliJ's debugger using a remote debugging target.
3. My annotation processor runs normally. I've added `processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage` statements to the `process` method and I they are logged correctly.
4. The only thing that is *not* working is the breakpoints. None of the breakpoints I set are hit.

I've tried several things: changing the classpath of the remote debugging target, different versions of maven-compiler-plugin, different options of that plugin (fork, ...), nothing helps.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is interference or a conflict with the `maven-toolchains-plugin`, which is also being used in my project. Once I removed that plugin from the POM, debugging and breakpoints work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Following issue maybe related.  Toolchains is definitely doing something strange when it comes to annotation processing: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOOLCHAINS-34