# how to find annotation processor for java and spring's annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to see the internal working of Java's and Spring's annotation
Like how `@Controller`, `@RequestMapping("/")` and all mapped inside, so I want to see Spring's Annotation Processor's Implementations.

Also same for `@Override` and other Java's Annotation Processor.

Comment: see this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587096/how-do-you-debug-java-annotation-processors-using-intellij

Comment: I think this answer is good news for you, but it only explain for @Overide
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189980/how-do-annotations-like-override-work-internally-in-java/18202623#18202623

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to see the implementation or where it is used, I usually use IntelliJ IDEA search usages feature.

Example for your specific request, I searched in all files after the imports 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping

[image]

You can use also the show usages feature, but you will you will need to configure it to skip comments to avoid noise.

Comment: The more easy way I found for IntelliJ, type "ctrl + shift + F" and select scope.